# GeoServer WPS service Raster Zonal Statistics does not give results when using text/csv format to define zone polygon

Tags: raster, geoserver, csv, zonal-statistics, wps

I am working with GeoServer 2.22 and I'm trying to use the `gs:RasterZonalStatistics` tool, through the WPS request builder that is provided in the "demos" in GeoServer. The tool runs fine when I use as input for the "zones - Zone polygon features for which to compute statistics" an shapefile.

My problem is that I want to use as input either JSON or preferably the text/csv option, and the output is empty. I have checked that my coordinates are in the same CRS as my raster and that the coordinates are given counterclockwise and that the polygon is closed.

When I use JSON, I format it as:

```
{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[92463.16443053566, 453115.6121168173],[91863.11388721458, 451418.7404136644],[93069.6374807694, 451221.9515308621],[93421.14967336296, 452890.0222223025], [92463.16443053566, 453115.6121168173]]]}
```

When I use text/csv, I format it as:

```
FID,the_geom
1,POLYGON(((92463.16443053566 453115.6121168173,91863.11388721458 451418.7404136644,93069.6374807694 451221.9515308621,93421.14967336296 452890.0222223025, 92463.16443053566 453115.6121168173))
```

Comment: That's wkt not csv

Comment: yes, thank you for the remark. i also tried with the altered code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RasterZonalStatistics` process is expecting a **FeatureCollection** rather than a simple polygon which is why your early attempts didn't work. I suspect that the problem with the CSV import is that it isn't quite smart enough to automatically detect that you are passing in a WKT geometry column, it's been a while since I looked at that code but as I recall it was mostly expecting to see an X and Y or Lat and Lon column and if it didn't see those it would proceed with no geometry column.

I would stick to use better supported formats with the WPS engine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Indeed it needed the '''FeatureCollection''' . It works in JSON format with: {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4],[x1,y1]]]]}}]}